# Shortcut for switching between applications

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I am using Unity desktop environment. I find it difficult to switch between multiple open applications frequently. I currently use the ALT+TAB to get list of open applications and then switch to the required one. I want to know whether we can switch directly to the required application by somehow ordering the applications and then switching to required application by some shortcut like ALT+3 for third application.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is already available. Pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd> has the same effect as clicking on the icons in launcher (numbered 1-9 from top to bottom). Since clicking on the icon goes to the window, you can use that. The <kbd>Super</kbd> for you is likely the Windows key. You can long-press on the <kbd>Super</kbd> for a list of shortcuts.